# Cómo poner un botón dentro de un formulario html que no reinicie la página

Tags: javascript, html5, formularios

Tengo un formulario y quisiera agregar un botón dentro de dicho formulario, pero que tenga como función agregar un `input`. Esta función la hice con JavaScript y funciona bien. El problema es que al estar dentro de un `form`, se reinicia la página y se borra el input que agregué.

He probado quitando la etiqueta `form` y funciona normal. Pero necesito que esté dentro de un `form` ya que es un registro. Me podrían ayudar a desvincular ese botón del formulario.

A continuación pongo el código que he avanzado:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Register Subjects</title>

    <!-- Google font -->

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- font awesome -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e70d054944.js"></script>

    <!-- style -->

    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
            background: #f5f5f5;
        }
        
        .abs-center {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            min-height: 100vh;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <div class="container p-5">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Register Subject</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Register students of the course
                        </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Register deliverables</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active text-center shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
                    <div class="container p-5">
                      <form>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fas fa-book"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject's name" aria-label="Subject's name" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <span class="input-group-text">Description</span>
                            </div>
                            <textarea class="form-control" aria-label="Description" placeholder="add a description of the course"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <select class="custom-select" id="teacher1">
                                      <option selected>Choose a teacher</option>
                                      <option value="1">One</option>
                                      <option value="2">Two</option>
                                      <option value="3">Three</option>
                                    </select>
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect02"><i class="fas fa-chalkboard-teacher"></i></label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div id="extra-teacher">

                        </div>

                        <div>

                        </div>

                        <button class="btn btn-success mb-3" onclick="add_teacher()">Add another teacher</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block mb-3">
                                    Register Subject
                            </button>
                          </form>  
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade text-center shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">b</div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade text-center shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">c</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
<script>

    function add_teacher() {
        function input_teacher() {
            var text = '<div class="input-group mb-3"><select class="custom-select" id="teacher"><option selected>Choose a teacher</option><option value="1">One</option><option value="2">Two</option><option value="3">Three</option></select><div class="input-group-append"><label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect02"><i class="fas fa-chalkboard-teacher"></i></label></div></div>'
            return text
        }
        
        document.querySelector('#extra-teacher').innerHTML = input_teacher()
    }
</script>

</html>
```

Si se dan cuenta, al estar dentro del `form` y dar clic en el botón, se redirecciona. ¿Cómo evito que pase eso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que todo botón dentro de un formulario va a actuar como un botón de envío (submit). Para evitar esto, puedes optar por una de estas opciones:

1. En el HTML, añádele `type="button"` al botón que no quieres que envíe el formulario. De ese modo le estás diciendo al navegador que ese botón es de hecho un botón y no un botón de envío.
2. En el JavaScript, añade `event.preventDefault()` a la función que llama el botón. De ese modo estarás indicando que no quieres que se realice la función por defecto de ese botón (que sería enviar el formulario).

Aquí puedes ver tu código con la primera opción:

> El código contiene otros *problemas* que harán que solo se pueda añadir un profesor adicional. Pero eso queda fuera del alcance de esta pregunta.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Register Subjects</title>

    <!-- Google font -->

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- font awesome -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e70d054944.js"></script>

    <!-- style -->

    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
            background: #f5f5f5;
        }
        
        .abs-center {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            min-height: 100vh;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <div class="container p-5">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Register Subject</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Register students of the course
                        </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Register deliverables</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active text-center shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
                    <div class="container p-5">
                      <form>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fas fa-book"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject's name" aria-label="Subject's name" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <span class="input-group-text">Description</span>
                            </div>
                            <textarea class="form-control" aria-label="Description" placeholder="add a description of the course"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <select class="custom-select" id="teacher1">
                                      <option selected>Choose a teacher</option>
                                      <option value="1">One</option>
                                      <option value="2">Two</option>
                                      <option value="3">Three</option>
                                    </select>
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect02"><i class="fas fa-chalkboard-teacher"></i></label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div id="extra-teacher">

                        </div>

                        <div>

                        </div>

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success mb-3" onclick="add_teacher()">Add another teacher</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block mb-3">
                                    Register Subject
                            </button>
                          </form>  
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade text-center shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">b</div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade text-center shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">c</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
<script>

    function add_teacher() {
       
        function input_teacher() {
            var text = '<div class="input-group mb-3"><select class="custom-select" id="teacher"><option selected>Choose a teacher</option><option value="1">One</option><option value="2">Two</option><option value="3">Three</option></select><div class="input-group-append"><label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect02"><i class="fas fa-chalkboard-teacher"></i></label></div></div>'
            return text
        }
        
        document.querySelector('#extra-teacher').innerHTML = input_teacher();
    }
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Los elementos `button` tienen un `type` (tipo) por defecto. El tipo por defecto es `submit`, esto quiere decir que se envían los datos del formulario al servidor.

Si especificas el tipo a `button`, el problema se soluciona ya que con esto estás diciendo que el botón no tiene un comportamiento definido a excepción de todos los eventos que tu mismo le indiques (en este caso la ejecución de la función `add_teacher`):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Register Subjects</title>

    <!-- Google font -->

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- font awesome -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e70d054944.js"></script>

    <!-- style -->

    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
            background: #f5f5f5;
        }
        
        .abs-center {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            min-height: 100vh;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <div class="container p-5">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Register Subject</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Register students of the course
                        </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Register deliverables</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active text-center shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
                    <div class="container p-5">
                      <form>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fas fa-book"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject's name" aria-label="Subject's name" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <span class="input-group-text">Description</span>
                            </div>
                            <textarea class="form-control" aria-label="Description" placeholder="add a description of the course"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <select class="custom-select" id="teacher1">
                                      <option selected>Choose a teacher</option>
                                      <option value="1">One</option>
                                      <option value="2">Two</option>
                                      <option value="3">Three</option>
                                    </select>
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect02"><i class="fas fa-chalkboard-teacher"></i></label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div id="extra-teacher">

                        </div>

                        <div>

                        </div>

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success mb-3" onclick="add_teacher()">Add another teacher</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block mb-3">
                                    Register Subject
                            </button>
                          </form>  
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade text-center shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">b</div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade text-center shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">c</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
<script>

    function add_teacher() {
        function input_teacher() {
            var text = '<div class="input-group mb-3"><select class="custom-select" id="teacher"><option selected>Choose a teacher</option><option value="1">One</option><option value="2">Two</option><option value="3">Three</option></select><div class="input-group-append"><label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect02"><i class="fas fa-chalkboard-teacher"></i></label></div></div>'
            return text
        }
        
        document.querySelector('#extra-teacher').innerHTML = input_teacher()
    }
</script>

</html>
```

Lo único que he hecho es actualizar esta parte de tu código para agregarle el `type="button"`:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success mb-3" onclick="add_teacher()">Add another teacher</button>
```

En el siguiente enlace puedes ver los atributos del elemento `button`:

- [button - Atributos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/button#Atributos)